# ¿Por qué me aparece este error en Swift?

Tags: condiciones, swift

Estoy usando unos condicionales muy simples y me da el siguiente error:

> unary operator cannot be separated from its operand.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

//SENTENCIAS IF

let myNumber = 5

//Una barra invertida y los paréntesis lo que aparece es la variable
//siempre y cuando tengamos un texto

if myNumber >= 5 && <= 10
{
    print("\(myNumber) es mayor que 5 y es menor que 10")
} else

{
    print("\(myNumber) es mayor que 10")
}
```

¿Alguien sabe cuál puede ser el error?

Comment: Necesitas el valor a comparar `myNumber <= 10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El uso que estás haciendo es incorrecto porque omites la variable a comparar en la segunda condición, tras el operador lógico.

Es decir cond1 && cond2, donde:

- cond1 es 'myNumber >= 5'
- cond2 es '<= 10'

```swift
import Foundation

let myNumber = 10

// Estas 2 formas son incorrectas
/*
 if myNumber >= 5 && <= 10 { ... }
 if myNumber (>= 5 && <= 10) { ... }
*/

// Tienes que indicar la segunda condición tras el operador lógico
if myNumber >= 5 && myNumber <= 10 {
    print("\(myNumber) entre 5 y 10")
} else {
    print("\(myNumber) entre 5 y 10")
}

// En tu caso hacer puedes comparar dentro de un rango, como en los códigos de las respuestas de red
if 5 ... 10 ~= myNumber {
    print("\(myNumber) entre 5 y 10")
} else {
    print("\(myNumber) entre 5 y 10")
}
```